# Grab the Last Date when a value changes

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to grab the last rundate when then churn value changed. I would need the result to return this:

```
> customer  billto   banner     rundate        churn    lastchurndate

> 976193     976193   GexPro     12/04/2019     true     11/26/2019
> 976193     976193   GexPro     11/26/2019     true     11/26/2019  
> 976193     976193   GexPro     11/19/2019     false    11/26/2019
```

This is the current raw data set:

```
> customer  billto   banner     rundate        churn    

> 976193     976193  GexPro     12/04/2019     true      

>976193     976193   GexPro     11/26/2019     true     

>976193     976193   GexPro     11/19/2019     false
```

The churn value changed on 11/26/2019 from False to True.

I need to know when the last date was when churn <> current churn date if I were to query on current rundate as of today.

I have a query where I was able to get 11/19/2019, but it's not quit right.

```
select
    v.st_cust_no
    ,v.bt_cust_no
    ,v.banner
    ,v.rundate
    ,v.churn
    ,case when c."last churn date" is null then v.rundate
        else c."last churn date"
     end as "last churn date" 
    ,c."last churn" 
    from 
     dwstage v
    left join 
    (    
    select 
     z.st_cust_no
    ,z.BT_CUST_NO
    ,z.banner
    ,z.rundate 
    ,z.churn as "current churn" 
    ,x.latest as "last churn date" 
    ,x.churn "last churn" 

    from dwstage    z

        inner join 
        (select 
             st_cust_no
            ,BT_CUST_NO
            ,banner
            ,churn
            ,max(rundate) as latest 
            from dwstage
            group by 
                 st_cust_no
                ,BT_CUST_NO
                ,banner
                ,churn) x

        on z.st_cust_no = x.st_cust_no
        and z.bt_cust_no = x.bt_cust_no
        and z.BANNER = x.BANNER
    where z.churn <> x.churn
    ) c
     on v.st_cust_no = c.st_cust_no
        and v.bt_cust_no = c.bt_cust_no
        and v.BANNER = c.BANNER
        and v.rundate = c.rundate
-- where v.st_cust_no = '14025'
order by 
    v.st_cust_no
   ,v.banner
   ,v.rundate desc 
;
```

Comment: What version of Oracle database do you have? (Such as 12.1.0.2 - run `select banner from v$version` and see the first row in the output, then report your version here.) Different solutions are available in different versions - the newer versions allow more efficient answers.

Comment: Also, I assume you need one row of output for each distinct `customer`, but please confirm. (And the other columns - other than `customer, rundate, churn` - should not be considered; I understand that `lastchurndate` is not in the table, but you must add it in the output, according to the rule you explained.)

Comment: Hi Mathguy, yes you are correct  "lastchurndate" is a new column from the base table. The version I am using is 

Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production

Comment: Can you please answer my other questions as well? Do you need the query to work separately for each customer? Hard to tell from your test data, since it only has one customer across all rows. And, what is the role of the other columns (if any)?

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of analytical functions as following:

```
Select * from
  (Select t.*,
          Row_number() over (partition by customer order by rundate desc nulls last) as rn
   from
     (Select t.*, 
             case when lag(chrun) over (partition by cutomer order by rundate) <> chrun then 1 end as chrunchanged
        From your_table t) t
  Where chrunchanged = 1)
Where rn = 1
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You want the date on every row, so you do not want any filtering.  This suggests window functions:

```
select s.*,
       max(case when prev_churn <> churn then rundate) over (partition by customer, billto) as last_churndate
from (select s.*,
             lag(churn) over (order by customer, billto order by rundate) as prev_churn
      from dwstage s
     ) s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 12.1 introduced the `match_recognize` clause, which can do very quick work on this kind of problem. Here is one way. I start with creating a small test table, with two different customers to test that the query works correctly on that more general scenario.

Table creation:

```
create table dwstage (customer, billto,  banner, rundate, churn) as
  select 976193, 976193, 'GexPro', to_date('12/04/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'true'  from dual union all
  select 976193, 976193, 'GexPro', to_date('11/26/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'true'  from dual union all
  select 976193, 976193, 'GexPro', to_date('11/19/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'false' from dual union all
  select 999999, 999999, 'Banner', to_date('03/21/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'false' from dual union all
  select 999999, 999999, 'Banner', to_date('04/21/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'true'  from dual union all
  select 999999, 999999, 'Banner', to_date('08/03/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'false' from dual union all
  select 999999, 999999, 'Other' , to_date('08/31/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'false' from dual
;
```

Query and output:

```
select customer, billto, banner, rundate, churn, lastchurndate
from   dwstage
match_recognize(
  partition by customer
  order     by rundate desc
  measures  final last(a.rundate) as lastchurndate
  all rows  per match
  pattern   (^ a+ b*)
  define    a as churn = first(churn)
)
;


  CUSTOMER     BILLTO BANNER RUNDATE    CHURN LASTCHURND
---------- ---------- ------ ---------- ----- ----------
    976193     976193 GexPro 12/04/2019 true  11/26/2019
    976193     976193 GexPro 11/26/2019 true  11/26/2019
    976193     976193 GexPro 11/19/2019 false 11/26/2019
    999999     999999 Other  08/31/2019 false 08/03/2019
    999999     999999 Banner 08/03/2019 false 08/03/2019
    999999     999999 Banner 04/21/2019 true  08/03/2019
    999999     999999 Banner 03/21/2019 false 08/03/2019
```